# Etymology of "mortgage" and "deed". Are they both related to "death"?

Tags: etymology

I read something that said the word *deed* was related to the word *dead*, deed being the document signifying ownership of a house and dead being no longer alive.

The article didn’t elaborate but after reading that I thought about it and concluded mortgage could be related to mortuary assuming the first assertion is true.  Any information about this would be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that [*deed* (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=deed&searchmode=none) is not much related to *dead*:

> *Old English dæd "a doing, act, action, transaction, event,*" from Proto-Germanic *dædis (cognates: Old Saxon dad, Old Norse dað, Old Frisian dede, Middle Dutch daet, Dutch daad, Old High German tat, German Tat "deed," Gothic gadeþs "a putting, placing"), from PIE *dhetis (cognates: Lithuanian detis "load, burden," Greek thesis "a placing, setting"), from *dhe- "place, put" (see do). Sense of "written legal document" is early 14c. As a verb, 1806, American English Related: Deeded; deeding.

while [*mortgage* (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Mortgage&searchmode=none) has some relation to it:

> late 14c., morgage, "conveyance of property as security for a loan or agreement," **from Old French morgage (13c.), mort gaige, literally "dead pledge" (replaced in modern Frech by hypothèque), from mort "dead" (see mortal (adj.)) + gage "pledge" (see wage (n.))**. *So called because the deal dies either when the debt is paid or when payment fails. Old French mort is from Vulgar Latin *mortus "dead," from Latin mortuus, past participle of mori "to die" (see mortal (adj.)). The -t- restored in English based on Latin.*
>   m/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Deed&searchmode=none

Comment: Indeed, a *deed* is a type of contract whose very creation requires a specific action, or deed (historically, "signed, sealed and delivered").